# Need help making a button play multiple sounds in Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, audio

I'm having an issue trying to get my code work for my Adobe Flash project. Basically I'm trying to get a button to play a random sound everytime it's clicked which works but I can't have that same code on the same frame for a different button which is why it gives me this error.

Here is my code:

```
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("19103_b.mp3");
var ci_diese:Sound = new Sound();
ci_diese.load(request);

var request_two:URLRequest = new URLRequest("19203_b.mp3");
var d_diese:Sound = new Sound();
d_diese.load(request_two);

var request_three:URLRequest = new URLRequest("19204_b.mp3");
var f_diese:Sound = new Sound();
f_diese.load(request_three);

var play_liste = 0;

var dictSounds = new Dictionary ();

dictSounds[1] = d_diese;
dictSounds[2] = ci_diese;
dictSounds[3] = f_diese;

fireweapon_H3AR.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler (event:MouseEvent) : void {
    play_liste = Math.ceil(Math.random () *3); 
    dictSounds[play_liste].play ();

ready_H3AR.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler (event:MouseEvent) : void {
    play_liste = Math.ceil(Math.random () *3); 
    dictSounds[play_liste].play ();}
}
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Readya.mp3");
var ci_diese2:Sound = new Sound();
ci_diese2.load(request);

var request_two:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Readyb.mp3");
var d_diese2:Sound = new Sound();
d_diese2.load(request_two);

var request_three:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Readyc.mp3");
var f_diese2:Sound = new Sound();
f_diese2.load(request_three);

var play_liste = 0;

var dictSounds = new Dictionary ();

dictSounds[1] = d_diese2;
dictSounds[2] = ci_diese2;
dictSounds[3] = f_diese2;

ready_H3AR.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler (event:MouseEvent) : void {
    play_liste = Math.ceil(Math.random () *3); 
    dictSounds[play_liste].play ();}
}
```

Any way to rewrite this to accommodate more than one button? The first half works up until it repeats itself at "import flash." I've been searching everywhere for answers so please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should not name two functions or two variables the same, because the last ones are going to overwrite the first ones.

For example

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("19103_b.mp3");
```

is then overwritten

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Readya.mp3");
```

The same happens with the button ready_H3AR an the function listener mouseDownHandler

By the way, you don't need to import the classes twice:

```
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll delete the duplicate functions

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a task or a block of code is intended to be used many times, it's better to put it in a function to get a simpler and more maintainable code.

So you can do like this :

```
var sounds:Array = [
    ['01.mp3', '02.mp3', '03.mp3'],     // sounds for the 1st button
    ['04.mp3', '05.mp3', '06.mp3']      // sounds for the 2nd button
];

var sound:Sound,
    sound_channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

function play_sound(sound_name:String): void 
{
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('mp3/' + sound_name);   
    sound = new Sound();
    sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_sound_loaded); 
    sound.load(request); 
}
function on_sound_loaded(e:Event): void 
{ 
    // if you want, you can stop the current playing sound 
    // otherwise you don't need the SoundChannel
    sound_channel.stop();
    sound_channel = Sound(e.target).play(); 
}

button_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, on_press);
button_02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, on_press);
function on_press(e:MouseEvent): void
{
    // to get values : 0, 1 or 2
    var random:int = int(Math.random () * sounds[0].length);
    // if it's the 1st button so pick the sound from the 1st sounds array
    if(e.currentTarget.name == 'button_01'){
        play_sound(sounds[0][random]);
    } else {
        play_sound(sounds[1][random]);
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: It definitely did! Thank you! Putting the sounds in the array is what I was looking for.